# SslStream responds differently when accessed as COM object

Tags: c#, c++, com, sslstream

I am working with an on a project where the bulk of the code is C++. The shop is migrating to C# in the long run, so where possible we are making new code in C# and exposing to C++ via COM.

I have wrapped an System.Net.Sockets.SslStream and a little bit of other functionality in a COM object that is intended to send and then receive messages. When calling the functions on this class from a test C# program I am able to send and receive messages without issue. Making the same calls, which are exposed via COM, seems to work as well, except I cannot receive data immediately after I send.

From the C# test data sends and receives quite quickly and I get the responses I should. From C++ I always get timeout errors. The data in the functions making the call to Read is identical in the C# test and from the C++ program. Much of the state in the SslStream is identical. Just after the write call and before the Read the only differences appear to be, several handles and what appear to be memory addressest, but I assume those are not important. At this same time I noticed that in an item called 'base', then inside an item called 'InnerStream', then inside 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream' there is a property called 'DataAvailable'. This is true in the C# test where it works and false in the C++ program where it fails. I am not aware of any meaningful difference between these project beyond what I have described.

I can provide further details about troubleshooting or snippets of code. I have not included code here because tjust the pieces related to the problem would still be immense. I hope there is some kind of magic answer as to what is going on, however the error is almost certainly in depth and very specific. I would appreciate anything that provides insight on further troubleshooting steps.

What kinds of complications does calling C# though COM impose that I may not have taken in account?

Where did the other sides message go if not into the SslStream buffer?

Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the answer, and it is unrelated to COM, C#, C++ and instead has to do with the formatting of the message being sent between the systems involved. The other system uses an extra carriage return to indicate the end of the message. When missing the remote system simply stops responding until another SSL session is started.

At a previous point in the project I was including an extra line break at the end of messages sent to the server. I had copied one of these messages to produce my entirely c# test. Several times I also took the messages being sent from both codebases and put them into a merge/diff viewer. I never noticed this difference because I had disabled white space matching.

From now on when I compare raw output to other raw output, I will make sure that none of my tools will hide differences from me.